# Doc2vec inference in gensim 0.12.3

Tags: gensim

I have upgraded gensim from 0.12.2 to 0.12.3 and I am facing an issue while inferencing in doc2vec. This is the code for performing inference:

```
doc = query.lower().split()
inf_vec = formmodel.infer_vector(doc)
similarF = formmodel.docvecs.most_similar([inf_vec])
```

When doc2vec model training and inference were done using version 0.12.3 this code gives results as shown below:

```
[(644539, 0.55715829133987427), (647249, 0.55713766813278198),...]
```

When doc2vec model training and inference were done using version 0.12.2 the same code gave results like so:

```
[(docId1, 0.55715829133987427), (docId2, 0.55713766813278198),....]
```

How do I get document labels instead of numbers in 0.12.3?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this thread for solution [gensim 0.12.3 inference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gensim/doc2vec$200.12.3/gensim/qBKh8DHFn-A/2cq9n_L1AAAJ)